# Find a program directory from within after turning to .exe using py2exe

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, pywin32

I am writing a code which I want to have details to its own directory. e.g. C:\Users\User\Desktop\helloworld.py

Is there a way to find it from within the program using pywin32 or any other module?

If so, once I turn it into .exe using py2exe will it still be able to find it's own directory(C:\Users\User\Desktop\dist\helloworld.exe)

I tried the following code:

```
print os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(sys.argv[0]))
```

This works but once I turn it into a .exe file it doesn't manage to run.... What other solutions can there be?
The error I get in the log file is the following error:
**Traceback (most recent call last): File "finddirectory.py", line 4, in  EOFError: EOF when reading a line**

Answer (score 0):

You can find that information on the py2exe wiki:

http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/WhereAmI